# Kernel Panic on VMware Workstation 7.1.3

Tags: linux, fedora, vmware-workstation, arch-linux

I've been trying to install either Arch Linux or Fedora 17 on VMWare Workstation (7.1.3). After I point to the right ISO image, I get the following error:

```
Booting the kernel
PANIC: early exception 0d rip:ffffffff81042dc4 error 0 cr2 0
```

I am trying to install it on a machine which has a 3rd generation i5 processor. After checking [A VMWare panic early exception fix for ivy bridge i3, i5, i7](http://www.basemont.com/panic_early_exception_i3_i5_i7_vmware_virtualbox_parallels), I tried to turn off the nosmep acpi. This is around, I get the same error but at a different address. Apparently, [others](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2139894) have faced this issue before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought this qualified as a valid question as per the 1st point in the FAQ, as the machine is a Business Workstation and since it concerned virtualization.... Is there a better way to ask this question or is there another place I can ask this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your hardware does not support virtualization or virtualization is not enabled in bios. Are you sure your hardware supports virtualization? 
please reboot your computer to bios, search for Processor menu and enable VT (Intel Virtualization Technology) if it is present. 
I hope it helps

What is your host operating system?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The hardware supports Virtualization. The machine runs both Win 7 and Fedora 17. We have Virtualbox on Fedora 17 upon which we run instances of Fedora, Ubuntu and XP. The host OS for the VMWare Workstation is Windows 7